# The <a> tag doesn't match the <div>

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I'm making a spiral shaped image gallery so when you click any image it will take you to another page. For that I used this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="rotulacion-embarcaciones">
        <a href="rotulacion-embarcaciones.html">
            <img src="embarcaciones/embarcaciones1.jpg" class="rotulacion-embarcaciones">
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotulacion-embarcaciones {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
padding: 40px;
top: 100px;
left:35px;
```

}

But the problem is that I can't click on the image because the `<a>` tag have some issues, look at the images of what the chrome inspector detects so you can know better what's happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FdbL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rtYY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHBcj.png

Comment: what if you move the class from your image to your a tag? the image children will inherit the position, although you'd need a new class for the image border radius

Comment: @fixmycode Do you mean this? : 

`<a href="blablabla" class= "rotulacion-embarcaciones"`

Comment: yes, then just add another class with border-radius to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having with the `a` is that all the content inside it is positioned absolutely. Things with `position:absolute` do not take up space in the normal page flow, which means that the `a` collapses down to size 0×0.

Solution: use another class for the image in the `a` and style it without using `position`.